# Ssl error while git cloning in server

Tags: git, ssl, cpanel

```
[sandipXXX@server applications]$ git clone https://github.com/sandipbhuyan/myblog.git
Cloning into 'myblog'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sandipbhuyan/myblog.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

While i am trying to clone a git repository from git it is always showing this message  i tried this

```
git config http.sslverify false
```

but the same is happening

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem (Ubuntu 18.04) with three steps:

(1) reset the ssl verification to be true:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

(2) reinstall ca-certificates:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

(3) modify the .gitconfig file:

```
cd ~/
vim .gitconfig
#(change two lines of the ".gitconfig" contents as below)
sslVerify = true
sslCAinfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: In case it helps, I was having this problem when setting up a VS Code devcontainer.  My host OS is Windows, and the devcontainer was Ubuntu.  Part of the decvontainer setup was copying my Windows .gitconfig over, which had a Windows path for the `sslCAinfo`, which couldn't work in the devcontainer.

Answer (score 0):

Pending the exact resolution of this certificate issue, you can at least try and switch to SSH:

```
git clone git@github.com:sandipbhuyan/myblog.git
```

Provided you [generated a public/private SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) (no need for a passphrase for now) and [registered your public key to your account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).